# How to handle mouse events in iOS 13 objective-c

Tags: objective-c, mouseevent, appkit, ios13, xcode11

iOS 13 finally introduced support for the mouse. I have been searching in vain for documentation on how to handle mouse events. In macOS 10+ there is NSEvent class https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent as part of AppKit. What is the corresponding class in iOS 13? Can someone point me to some documentation/examples, please? I have tried the code in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingMouseEvents/HandlingMouseEvents.html but it does not work in iOS 13. I am using Xcode 11. I am particularly interested in getting the mouse event information (e.g., pressedMouseButtons, mouseLocation, buttonNumber).

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self setFrameColor:[NSColor redColor]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    [self setFrameColor:[NSColor greenColor]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> There seem to be no public APIs for this feature.

For some of what you want here, there is starting in iPadOS 13.4!

> All "mouse" events on iOS 13 register as regular touch events, just
> like events produced by AssistiveTouch. You're unable to check for the
> source of these events.

This is correct. Lets dig in...

### Background and links

On iPad, starting with iPadOS 13.4, trackpads and mice are supported *without* any accessibility features enabled. Note that iPhone does *not* get this native support. The API I discuss below still applies, but will only work on the iPhone with pointing device support for AssistiveTouch enabled.

We go over the event and gesture API here:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10094/

If you check out that video in the Developer app, there are code snippets from the video included.

And some of the compatibility mode affordances I describe below are detailed here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/uiapplicationsupportsindirectinputevents

*(edit)*
GameController.framework does show all the connected mice as I mention below, and you can set up change handlers for each.  However, there's no way to see the ID from these devices there:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gcmouse/3626182-mice
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10617/

### Pointer movement and clicks

Pointer movement is driven by `UIEvent.EventType.hover`. You handle that with a `UIHoverGestureRecognizer`.

Clicks on a pointing device are transformed into a `UITouch` instances.  As a compatibility affordance, these are all `UITouch.TouchType.direct` by default. That's the same as a finger-based touch.

If you opt into UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents in your application's info.plist key, clicks on pointing devices are transformed into `UITouch.TouchType.indirectPointer`. That will allow you to distinguish these touches from finger-based touches, and you can target these touches specifically using API like `UIGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes`.

### Button mask

With UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents, you'll be able to recognize that a touch from a pointing device happened.  To recognize the specific button, you'll want to look at either `UIEvent.buttonMask` or `UIGestureRecognizer.buttonMask`. Note that `UIGestureRecognizer`'s property is from the last event processed.

`.buttonMask` will show you the set of buttons pressed during an event.

### Conclusion

As I understand it you wanted to accomplish the following:

1. Recognize clicks from a pointing device
2. Determine which button was pressed
3. Determine *which* device the click came from.

For #1, you can use UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents to get the new `UITouch.TouchType.indirectPointer`, which will allow you to distinguish these touches.

For #2, you can use `.buttonMask` on either `UIEvent` or `UIGestureRecognizer`.

For #3, there is not currently API to achieve this on iOS.

*(edit)*
A co-worker mentioned that GameController.framework might help with some of this.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller

You'll be able to see all the connected mice with `GCMouse.mice()` and be notified when they connect:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gcmouse/3626182-mice

Unfortunately, you won't be able to see the ID of the mouse here either. Still, it gives you something to consider.

Check out this video that dives into more of the details on GameController.framework support for pointing devices and keyboards:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10617/

Comment: Thank you @moseley for your detailed reply. I tried to use the code snippets shown in the videos and the definitions in the provided documentation and have 2 additional questions:

1) Where is GCMouse defined? It does not appear to be part of the GameConrtoller.framework How do I access this class? **import GCMouse** gives me an error: No such module 'GCMouse'. I added the GameController.framework to my project but there is no GCMouse framework:-)

2) Is there a way to set the pointer position programmatically to some screen coordinates, say the center of the screen?

Comment: My mistake: I overlooked the fact that GCMouse is only available in iOS 14.0+ and macOS 11.0+ while I am currently using iOS 13.5.1 and macOS 10.15.5

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be no public APIs for this feature.

All "mouse" events on iOS 13 register as regular touch events, just like events produced by AssistiveTouch. You're unable to check for the source of these events.

Note: This is an accessibility feature, you shouldn't rely on it being enabled, and there is no way to detect if it's enabled or to force the user to enable it.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful reply. It's a bit disappointing that there is no public API and especially that there is no way to check for the source of the events. My app is designed to use two mice in tandem and getting the source ID is critical. Could anyone suggest a possible work around, please? As for the fact that this is an accessibility feature, I assume that I can always ask the user upfront to enable it. Anything wrong with that?!?

Comment: I was able to get the "mouse" events using UITouch and UIEvent,  but nothing in the descriptions of the touch and event gives me info about the source of the event. All I need to determine is: 1) The ID of the mouse that was clicked. 2) Which mouse button was clicked (left or right). Any suggestion on how to accomplish that?

Comment: @ValNenov It's not possible to check for the mouse that resulted in said event. As for buttons, I believe it depends on how the user sets their own buttons, and can vary from device to device.

Comment: I wonder if anyone from the Apple iOS 13 development team is reading these posts?!? It will be nice to hear back from them. Access to this functionality is easily available on Android 9, API 28.

Comment: It's been more than a month since I posted this question and so far there has been NO satisfactory answer. How can I convince the Apple iOS 13 development team to consider adding this seamingly basic functionality to the iOS 13 API? Namely: 1) Get the ID of the mouse that was clicked especially when more than one mouse is connected at the same time. 2) Which mouse button was clicked (left or right) - UP and DOWN events. I have sent this suggestion through the official online channels for recommendations to Apple but no reply. Any suggestions?